# What is the difference in sending data using json.dumps and by normal python dictionary?

Tags: django, python-3.x, api

i am using an api to do a post method and i used Requests library to perform the post.

```
 data_post = requests.post(url='https://proxy.vox-cpaas.in/api/user',
                          data={'authtoken': '945e5f0f_ssss_408e_pppp_ellll234122',
                                'projectid': "pid_a44444fae2_454542_41d4_8630_6454545cdafff12",
                                'username': "username",
                                'password': "user.username"})
```

the above data post worked successfully.

but

```
   data_post = requests.post(url='https://proxy.vox-cpaas.in/api/user',
                          data=json.dumps({'authtoken': '945e5f0f_ssss_408e_pppp_ellll234122',
                                'projectid': "pid_a44444fae2_454542_41d4_8630_6454545cdafff12",
                                'username': "username",
                                'password': "user.username"}))
```

the 2nd code didnt worked for me

please someone explain me the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way of **postng data as json with `requests`** - use `json` parameter:

```
r = requests.post(url, json=my_dictionary)
```

this way `requests` will encode dictionary for you (no need for json.dumps()) and will set correct `Content-Type` header.

---

In first example, when you pass `python dictionary` directly to `requests data` - result is [**form-encoded data**](https://2.python-requests.org//en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#make-a-post-request) with `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

In the second one - you pass `string which contains serialized json` to `requests data`. However, as `data` is just a string - `requests` may not identfy that it is json, and not set `Content-Type` or set it `Content-Type: "text/plain"`, and receiving side may not recognise it.

For correct request with json body you need `"Content-Type": "application/json"`.

You may want to explicitly set `content-type` in `headers`:

```
r = requests.post(
    url,
    data=json.dumps(my_dictionary),
    headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}
)
```

But `requests` contains **`json`** [parameter](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) to simplify these things.